# sync postman with azure devops

Tags: postman, azure-devops-rest-api

I can succesfully run postman tests in azure devops is there a way to

1. Create a Repo "MyCollection"
2. Run a "Cron" pipeline that takes the collection and saves it to the repo?

any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this extension [Get Postman Scripts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OneLuckiDev.getPostmanJSON), by default it will download your postman json file and save it to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, then we could push the files to Azure DevOps repo via git cmd.

```
cd  $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
git config --global user.name "{email}"
git checkout master
git add .
git commit -m "Sync postman json file to Azure DevOps Repo"
git push https://{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_git/{repo name}
```

You could also check this [doc](https://apievangelist.com/2020/01/22/three-ways-to-use-postman-and-azure-devops/) for more details.

**Update1**

YAML

```
- task: oneLuckiGetPostmanScripts@1
  displayName: 'Get Postman Script'
  inputs:
    fileLocation: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Postman'
    apiKey: '{key}'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for this . Just seen this . Reading and trying to see if I can implement it in a task

Comment: thanks for your time do you know  if can tell which collection to save? is it possible to use a newman task to export the collection and save it to repo , doing the following crashes   with "no such file or directory open"- task: oneLuckiGetPostmanScripts@1
   inputs:
     fileLocation: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Postman'
     apiKey: '$(PostmanApiKey)'
     pauseDuration: '100'
     downloadEnvironments: false

Comment: Hi @developer9969, I just have one collection and it save the josn file to my repo. In addition, could you share the detail log here? According to the error message, it seems cannot find the path, I have updated the answer, you could check it and then kindly share the result here.